# Mysql-Html string problem

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, joomla

I have a table, in joomla I'm getting the following data:
[image]

```
1. fc k��ln - vfl wolfsburg
germany 1. bundesliga
```

so I created a test page, I set up the header as utf-8, and everything was fine, I received the wanted data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4e36e64eb34d2
            [team1] => 1. FC Köln
            [team2] => VFL Wolfsburg
            [league] => Germany 1. Bundesliga
            [sport] => Soccer
            [time] => 2011-08-06 15:30:00
        )

)
```

I also check the joomla header and it's contains the charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your database connection has to be set UTF8

> set the mysql connection charset in includes/database.php file at about line 102 (second line below)

```
$this->_table_prefix = $table_prefix; 
//@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $this->_resource); // THIS IS THE LINE TO UNCOMMENT 
$this->_ticker = 0; 
$this->_og = array();
```

Ofcourse your data in table has to be utf-8, check this.

Other possibible thing to check is if your browser sees this page as utf8 (in firefox: View->character encoding)

Comment: This is hepl a little bit, before I had two question marks, now I have only one:)

Comment: I have figured out the problem, before the upload I'm executing this  ( "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your files are in wrong encoding? I was having similar problem whan my files were in CP-1251, all data were in UTF-8 and I needed to show danish symbols. Changing file-encoding has solved this problem. Try, maybe it will be helpfull for you too.

Comment: Yes, I know this problem, but beside the mysql data, I also printing out other data which are good.

Comment: Are you using any string php functions(strpos, str_replace, strcmp, sustr, etc)? As far as I know they don't work with ust8-strings. Try to use mb_-prefixed function for string manipulations(functions from php extention called mb_string).